# How does one send the image background behind the buttons while using Interface builder in Xcode 4.1

Tags: xcode4.1

The earlier version of xcode had a layout option in which one could select push to back. But the new version does not have it

Answer (score 8):

Click the **Editor** menu, then select **Arrange** > **Send to Back**.

Answer (score -1):

In XCode 8 you go to the menu bar on the top of the screen then click Edit >  Arrange >   Send to Back. This also Works for moving an item behind a single item or in front of an item.